# In Azure, is it possible to increase the NIC bandwidth limit without increasing VM size?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I see in this answer that the bandwidth limit is depending on the machine size: [Azure cloud service network bandwith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403714/azure-cloud-service-network-bandwith)

But is there a way to increase that limit without increasing the machine size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bandwidth limits are tied to VM size.

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth is purely based on your VM size, so you will not be able to modify that however you can use Accelerated networking it's a feature designed to improve network performance, including latency, throughput, and CPU utilisation. While accelerated networking can improve a virtual machine’s throughput, it can do so only up to the virtual machine’s allocated bandwidth.